# the specified user group SQLServerMSSQLUSer does not exist

Tags: sql-server

[image]

I have a problem with installing SQL Server 2008 Standard, during the installation a message pops with the error

> the specified user group SQLServerMSSQLUSer does not exist

I'm trying to install it on a Windows 2003 server sp2 after uninstalling SQL Server 2008 Express edition.

Please help me to save this issue.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to upgrade the express edition, I think it has something to do with the original security group, used during the installation of the express edition, that no loner exists on your system.

If the currently installed SQL Server Express edition functions, try to quit setup, start the management console, and look for this group, or some "unlinked" ADO object, in the security tab.

Might be as simple as deleting this faulty item and then trying to reinstall.

Comment: I uninstalled already the express (before installing the new standard). I searched for this user at the domain, some DC's had this user but it was "hided", it was founded at the search but i couldn't see it inside any ou containers...nevertheless, I deleted it, tried to install again and it fails...

Comment: Have you deleted the user from the DC? or from the currently working instance of SQL Express? Try to search for any reference to this user from SQL Express objects.

Answer (score 0):

`SQLServerMSSQLUser` is one of the standard groups that SQL Server creates to handle permissions.

If I had to guess you are not an administrator on the machine and don't have permissions to create the group.

Here are a couple of links I found that describe similar problems.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/77efd493-ad01-48cf-a804-a1babc90e975/

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1207218-391-1.aspx#bm1207251

Comment: hi, I even tried with the domain administrator user. i created a new user in AD and replicated successfully the site(if it helps).....

Comment: Try adding the group manually (it's a local group, not domain) then try the install.